# Unable to execute woocommerce_order_status_completed hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook is not executing while placing orders. I have added the below code in `functions.php` file to `console.log` order id:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'console_to_order_items_on_competed_status', 10, 1);
function console_to_order_items_on_competed_status( $order_id ){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('order id: "<?php echo $order_id ?>"');
</script>
<?php
}
```

The above code is not executing. I have also tried to add `do_action` as below:

```
do_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'console_to_order_items_on_competed_status')
```

but no luck at all. Please help me to get over this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want execute function on order place You can use this hook:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'your_order_details',  1, 1  );
    function your_order_details($order_id){ ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('order id: "<?php echo $order_id ?>"');
         </script>
    <?php }
```

Do remember to NOT place any $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart() sentence within these methods as it will remove the item in the cart and leave other checkout method unable to proceed further.

Try it & let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: @John Doe Please remove other unwanted hook If you are using in your code then try again. It should work. Or You can try woocommerce_thankyou hook which suggested by @
raju_eww if you want to get data in your thank you page after placing an order.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have removed unwanted hooks and its working perfectly now. Thanks

Comment: I am receiving this error `Use of undefined constant  1 - assumed ' 1' ` for this line: `add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'your_order_details', 1, 1 );`

Comment: The error was due to missed opening bracket after defining the function.

Answer (score 0):

To get order id when order is placed use below code will work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );

function action_woocommerce_thankyou()
{
   $current_order_id = wc_get_order( $order_id );
}
```

you will get order id in `$current_order_id` variable